# how to make a js snippet that can be reused on remote sites like fb api and tweet feeds

Tags: javascript

I'm interested in making a js snippet that will allow webmasters to insert a snippet on their site, and then it will create an html element (possibly button) in place, and when clicked post the url and title to my site, and open my site in a new window so the user can see the url + title as a new item on his/her list.

Facebook does this with all their like boxes and twitter with their feeds - but how is this actually done?

Comment: You are looking for some sort of share-bottom? Terrible explained in first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctaly,
one way would be by passing the current page url `location.href` and title `document.title` in the the url to your processing page, then you would validate extract the tit and location values for the requested url

```
    <script>
    function opens(){
    var j,w,s,u;
    j=document.title;
    w=j.replace(/"/g,'%22');
    w=j.replace(/&/g,'%26');
    u = "tit="+w+"&location="+encodeURIComponent(location.href);
    var nwin = window.open("landingpage.php?"+u, "subWindow", "height=400,width=700");        
    }


    function placeButtonWhatEver(ButtonText){
    var eml = document.createElement("span");
    var tex = document.createTextNode(ButtonText);
    eml.appendChild(tex);
    eml.onclick= opens;
    document.body.appendChild(eml);

    // FOR you to do think about it ; depends how you implement it; 
    // if there is a <A> which could be after the empeded script
    // remove the next child say a link with hardcoded title and url values
    // 
    }

    </script>


    <script>placeButtonWhatEver('Click Vote to like This')</script><!-- <a href="landingpage.php?tit=pagetitke&location=http"></a> -->
```

.

If you wanted it to still work with javascript being disabled you would append `title and url` on to a href on set `a's` target to `_blank`